# How to set QGridLayout in particular position after removing one of its widget

Tags: c++, qt, qgridlayout

I am using `QGridLayout` to add one `QPushButton` and one `QTextEdit`. but whenever i am hiding and removing `QTextEdit widget` then `QPushButton` is coming on the position of `QTextEdit`.

Initially `QPushButton` is in position lets say `(0,0)` and `QTextEdit` is in position `(100,0)`. Then on removing `QTextEdit QPushButton` is coming on `QTextEdit` position ie, at position `(100,0)`.

```
layout->addWidget(button1,0,0,1,1, Qt::AlignCenter);
layout->addWidget(text1,0,1,1,1);
```

On pressing delete key i am removing QTextWidget:

```
layout->removeWidget(text1);
```

So i think i have to set the position of `QGridLayout` so that everytime after removing `widget` it should be in its proper position.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If it's possible to post a screenshot it could be helpful in seeing the issue more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon your screenshot it looks like the column is completely removed when you remove the `QTextWidget`. You can try experimenting with setting the visibility of the `QTextWidget` to false rather than removing it.

```
text1->setVisible( false );
```

Although based upon the [QGridLayout doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#details) this may have the same result.

Or when you remove the `QTextEdit` replace it with a [QSpacerItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qspaceritem.html) so the column isn't completely remove.

If that still doesn't work I would next try changing your align of the `QPushButton` to `Qt::AlignLeft`.

```
layout->addWidget(button1,0,0,1,1, Qt::AlignLeft);
```

If you're not happy with that I would try using a [QHBoxLayout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qhboxlayout.html) rather than the `QGridLayout` to layout the items horizontally. Or you could always use the `QHBoxLayout` within the first row/column of the `QGridLayout`, it's ultimately up to your future use cases.

For example:

```
QHBoxLayout* hLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
hLayout->addWidget( button1, 0, Qt::AlignLeft );
hLayout->addWidget( text1, 0, Qt::AlignLeft );
qGridLayout->addLayout ( hLayout, 0, 0, Qt::AlignLeft );
```

Again with the `QHBoxLayout` and `QGridLayout` (might no longer need to use the grid) you may have to play with the alignments to get the results you want. Something like this might work

Comment: @Rupesh Updated my answer based upon your screenshot, hopefully that helps point you in the right direction.